# Incorrect parameter type for operator '<'. Expected DateTime, received Date

Tags: formula

I am trying to keep an alert in the form by creating a formula field, and I am getting the following error:

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '<'. Expected DateTime, received Date

```
IF(
    Passport_submission_date__c  <  TODAY() ,
    'Sorry! The submission date is expired ',
    TEXT( Passport_submission_date__c  -  TODAY() ) & ' days left for submission ' 
)
```

Answer (score 5):

The error here is pretty self-explanatory.

The `TODAY()` function returns a `Date`, and your `Passport_submission_date__c` field is a `Datetime`.

Those two types cannot be directly compared, so you need to either make both of them a `Date`, or both of them a `Datetime`.

Assuming you only really care about the date portion, you'd want to convert your `Passport_submission_date__c` into a `Date`, which you can do using the `DATEVALUE()` function.

As always, [the Formula Operators and Functions documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions.htm&type=5) is a good thing to reference.